# Python pop and append are not moving all elems in list1 to list 2

Tags: python

Why do pop and append not finish out the entire loop? My first guess was that pop didn't readjust the index of the original list, but that doesn't appear to be true when I print(txt[0]) to confirm it's still at the front. I'm trying to figure out why the below does not work. Thank you.

```
txt = 'shOrtCAKE'
txt = list(txt)
new_list = []

for x in txt:
    value = txt.pop(0)
    new_list.append(value)

print(new_list)
print(txt)
print(txt[0])
```

Comment: Do not modify a list you are iterating over.

Comment: You are altering the list as you loop ever it. There are *many* questions about this in the archive.

Comment: this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't modify the list while iterating over it. Instead use this code

```
for x in txt:
    value = x
    new_list.append(value)
txt = [] # assuming you want txt to be empty for some reason
```

But then if you end up printing `txt[0]` you'll end up with error as the list index will be out of range

However you don't really need to be looping. Just do the following:

```
new_list = txt[:] # [:] ensures that any changes done to txt won't reflect in new_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not remove elements from a list that you are iterating over.  In this case, you are not even *using* the values of the list obtained during iteration.

There are various possibilities if you still want to use `pop`, which *don't* involve iterating over `txt`. For example:

- Loop a fixed number of times (`len(txt)` computed at the start):

```
for _ in range(len(txt)):
    new_list.append(txt.pop(0))
```

- Loop while `txt` is not empty:

```
while txt:
    new_list.append(txt.pop(0))
```

- Loop until `pop` fails:

```
while True:
    try:
        new_list.append(txt.pop(0))
    except IndexError:
        break
```

Of course, you don't have to use `pop`. You could do this for example:

```
new_list.extend(txt)  # add all the elements of the old list
txt.clear()  # and then empty the old list
```